# Superscript citations without brackets with the `revtex4-1` document class

Tags: citing, revtex

Is it possible to achieve citations that are superscript and don't have brackets using the `revtex4-1` document class?

An example of how they should look:

> Afirmation<sup>3,4</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Phys. Rev. B citation style, so `\usepackage[aps,prb,citeautoscript]{revtex4-1}` is all that is needed. The `[citeautoscript]` is optional, but takes care of putting the citation after punctuation if necessary, as is Phys. Rev. B house style.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to add

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```

to the preamble of you latex file. This will provide a superscript, but will leave the bibliography as the usual separate section.

Comment: This gives superscripts, but still with `(` `)`.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal It works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

As the revtex4-1 document class loads the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/natbib.html) package, it is responsive to natbib's options and commands. The natbib command `\setcitestyle{super}` does what you want.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\setcitestyle{super}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: this option seem to keep the brackets in the reference list at the end

Answer (score 4):

A general way (working for revtex, but also - everything else) is to add:

```
\setcitestyle{super,open={},close={}}
```

Here `open` and `close` stand for opening and ending sequences. By default it is `open={(}` and `close={)}`, but you are free to use anything, including empty sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch of a biblatex solution:

```
\usepackage[autocite=footnote,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\let\cite\autocite
```

Now when you write `Something something\cite{key}` the citation will be placed in a footnote at the bottom of the page

Comment: According to p.11 of the revtex4-1 documentation, "[c]ertain packages are (should be) loaded by this class in any case: [...] natbib." This means that the class is incompatible with biblatex.

Comment: This solution doesn't actually work particularly well with multiple citations at the same place anyway. But revtex being incompatible with biblatex is, in my view, a reason not to use revtex...